# How to identify which process that printout last login in Centos 7

Tags: centos7, login

I made changes last few months to the Centos 7 and I forgot what did I do. After that, everytime I login into my system, I can see that I got 2 extra notification about last login as shown in the picture. How do I know what processes that printed out this one so that I can revert back everything.

This is Centos 7 64bit

[Last login notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIzyV.png)

Comment: Did you try `history`? Maybe that will remind you what you did.

Comment: @MichaelHampton forgot to tell in the question that, the changes that I made was few months ago.

Comment: Meaning that, using history command I can only see recent changes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do this, but if you want to permanently disable Last login messages you make lastlog file immutable.

`> /var/log/lastlog`

`chattr +i /var/log/lastlog` (you might need sudo for non root user)

Comment: Yes, but then it would just print the same three messages forever, right?

Comment: you're correct. you can empty the log file before making it immutable. Thanks

Comment: I'm not trying to disable the last login notification but I need to know which process that printed out the extra login information. Note after clearing the above log file, I can see 2 duplicate notification about last login (both are the same notification). So the other one where did that come from?